# Export/view next page/refresh action from Crystal report not using filter condition and showing all the data

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal report in VB.NET web application.
IDE: VS 2010 Ultimate
Crystal Report installed: V13.0.16

I am able to view my crystal report with data, but when i click the refresh button or next page button or export option in CR menu. 
the whole filter condition is reset and all the data related to the report is displayed/exported.
when i re enter URL which has filter condition then it loads the data with filters.

Request.QueryString() is used to get the filter details
and report details.

I need help at the earliest. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue which is posted above.
The application was developed using Crystal report version 13.0.0.99 (approximately 6 years before). I tried to upgrade it with latest version but it didn't help me on time. When i use the version which is used during development solved the error. The export or next page or refresh post back didn't reset the report content.

I am not sure how to fix it with most recent version of crystal report. This [Discussion](http://scn.sap.com/message/16520767#16520767) sounds like a solution with latest version but i don't have additional time to use it. I hope this could help some one in need.